# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936, throw err; ^ ........while trying to create a folder on my windows terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, frontend, npx

While trying to create a frontend application to consume my django backend through the GraphQL API, I went into downloading `node.js` I'm getting that error while try to run `npx @vue/cli create frontend --default` on my git bash terminal. Below is what was being shown to me.

```
Error: Cannot find module '../util/utimes.js'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Francisco Technics\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\15e985e3d7a3258b\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy-sync\copy-sync.js
- C:\Users\Francisco Technics\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\15e985e3d7a3258b\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy-sync\index.js
- C:\Users\Francisco Technics\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\15e985e3d7a3258b\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\Francisco Technics\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\15e985e3d7a3258b\node_modules\@vue\cli\lib\create.js
- C:\Users\Francisco Technics\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\15e985e3d7a3258b\node_modules\@vue\cli\bin\vue.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Francisco Technics\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\15e985e3d7a3258b\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\copy-sync\copy-sync.js:6:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Francisco Technics\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\15e985e3d7a3258b\\node_modules\\fs-extra\\lib\\copy-sync\\copy-sync.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Francisco Technics\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\15e985e3d7a3258b\\node_modules\\fs-extra\\lib\\copy-sync\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Francisco Technics\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\15e985e3d7a3258b\\node_modules\\fs-extra\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Francisco Technics\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\15e985e3d7a3258b\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\lib\\create.js',
    'C:\\Users\\Francisco Technics\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache\\_npx\\15e985e3d7a3258b\\node_modules\\@vue\\cli\\bin\\vue.js'
```

what can I do appease this bug, i totally no nothing about node.js

Comment: it is saying missing module `utimes.js`. Either install that or import it (if you already have it installed)

Comment: @roger i haven't installed it. please can you help me with the command to it install it on my command line